# How to create custom tasks for executingg .bat in terminal and bind shortcut key for it in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a test.bat file and I want to execute it using tasks and keyboard shortcut.

For example I have test.bat file at "D:\demo\test.bat" location and I want to add a keyboard shortcut (ex. "ctrl+e"), so that if I press this key then my batch file should get automatically execute in terminal.

Please guide me on this.